# How to make next-auth User Session Data Globally accessible from _app.js server-side?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, getserversideprops

What is the best way to make `next-auth` `user` data in `session` globally accessible in all pages server-side?

or do I need to manually add `getServerSideProps` to every page to get the `session` `user` data?

`<Provider session={pageProps.session}></Provider>` is in `_app.js` `return` function so do I need a `hoc` `wrapper` component for this?

I tried using `getInitialProps`:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, initialLoginStatus }) {

   console.log(initialLoginStatus);

   ....

  return (

     <React.Fragment>

          <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
             ...
          </Provider>

     </React.Fragment>

  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ( ctx ) => {

  if (typeof window === "undefined") {

    return {
      initialLoginStatus: `test`
    }

  } else {

    return {
      initialLoginStatus: `error`
    }
  }

}
```

but I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined`
for `<Provider session={pageProps.session}>`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an "_app.js" file in the "pages" folder you have to create one by putting this inside:

```js
import {Provider} from 'next-auth/client'

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
    return (
        <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Then in your page you have to use this to use the sessions:

```
import {useSession} from 'next-auth/client'
```

&

```
const [session, loading] = useSession()
```

And you can get the name of the user by doing for example:

```
session.user.name
```

Which would give for example in the code you provided:

```js
import {useSession} from 'next-auth/client'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, initialLoginStatus }) {

   const [session, loading] = useSession()
   
   console.log(session.user.name)
   console.log(session)

   console.log(initialLoginStatus);

   ....

  return (

     <React.Fragment>

          <Provider session={pageProps.session}>
             ...
          </Provider>

     </React.Fragment>

  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ( ctx ) => {

  if (typeof window === "undefined") {

    return {
      initialLoginStatus: `test`
    }

  } else {

    return {
      initialLoginStatus: `error`
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: the issue is I getting `undefined` if I `console.log` `session.user` right after `const [ session, loading ] = useSession()`, it is `undefined`, but `client-side` `await getSession();` works

Comment: I expected exactly the same behavior. It is indeed missleading from the docs but it is not enough with the wrappers in _app.js. You need to activate SSR and pass down server side session.

_app.js
...
import { useSession, getSession } from 'next-auth/client'
...
```
// Export the `session` prop to use sessions with Server Side Rendering
    export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      return {
        props: {
          session: await getSession(context)
        }
      }
    }
```